# Makefiles: converting file extension

Tags: c++, makefile

first of all I'd like to point out that I'm fairly new to makefiles, so sorry if I write something idiotic :)

I have a makefile with a variable name SRC, which is a list of my source files with extension *.cpp. I transform this list in a list of object files (extension *.o) with the following instruction:

```
OBJ = $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)
```

Now I'd like to expand my makefile in a way that my list of source files contains *.cpp and *.cu files. And I'd like the object files list to contain all of my file names with extension *.o. To achieve that, I have my SRC variable containing the *.cpp files and a new SRC_cu variable containing *.cu files and I do the following:

```
OBJ = $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o)
OBJ += $(SRC_cu:%.cu=%.o)
```

That works fine, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do the same with one instruction, that is, just having a SRC variable with mixed extensions and saying something like "convert all my files, with extension x or y, to a *.o file".

Comment: `OBJ = $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o) $(SRC_cu:%.cu=%.o)` ?

Comment: Which `make`?  Different `make` behave differently.

Comment: Thanks John, that works. But maybe I wasn't specific enough.
I have something like:
SRC = a.cpp
SRC += b.cpp
SRC_cu = d.cu

And I'd like to have just one SRC including all 3 files:

SRC = a.cpp
SRC += b.cpp
SRC += d.cu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even more generic option would be:

```
OBJ := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC)))
```

This will remove a suffixes of any type from the filenames in `SRC` and add `.o` to each filename.

Comment: Thanks a lot MadScientist, that was a great tip! It works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
OBJ := $(SRC:%.cpp=%.o) 
OBJ := $(OBJ:%.cu=%.o)
```

It uses only one variable SRC which contains the .cpp and .cu file list.

Though this cant be put in a single line since it uses the recusive variable OBJ. Dont forget to use `:=` instead of just `=` because `OBJ` is used recursively.

You cant directly pase different file extensions in a single line because the behavior of the wildcards. though you can have closest possible solution